# logstash csv filter to handle quoted text

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using the http_poller plugin to hit a web page which i am using to monitor the status of a service. This is one of those old services that has not dev resource to improve further.
http_poller is running ok and including the following in the message field

```
{"total_queue":0,"temp_queue":0,"processed":1926}
```

I would like to filter the message field into 3 fields like this

total_queue  :0 
temp_queue   :0 
processed    :1926

To date my filter syntax has resulted in

```
error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [total_queue]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"{\"total_queue\":0,\"temp_queue\":0,\"processed\":1612}\""}}}}}
```

This is what i have been playing with.

```
filter {
csv {
columns => ["total_queue", "temp_queue", "hospital"]
source => "message"
separator => "  "
skip_empty_columns => true
quote_char => "$"
#      convert => {
#        "column1" => "integer"
#        "column2" => "integer"
#        "column3" => "integer"
#      }
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since your input is in JSON already, you don't need to use a `csv` filter at all. Simply add `codec => json` in your http_poller input and your event will get all the fields from the JSON input.

Comment: "doh" - worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is in JSON already, you don't need to use a `csv` filter at all.

Simply add `codec => json` in your http_poller input and your event will get all the fields from the JSON input.

```
input {
  http_poller {
    ...
    codec => json             <--- add this
  }
}
filter {
   #remove csv
}
```